# SQL Server 2012 : extract Regex groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2012

I have text in my database in Markdown format. I'd like to extract links and count the number of matching links I have. I can get a listing of text blocks that contain links using a query similar to this:

```
SELECT post_text
FROM posts p
WHERE p.body like '%\[%](http%)%' ESCAPE '\'
```

How do I go to the next step though, and just extract the link portion of the text (the part that is in the parenthesis)? If I can get this, I can count the number of times this specific link is in my dataset.

Some sample data:

```
"Visit [Google](http://google.com)"    -> Should return "http://google.com"
"Get an [iPhone](http://www.apple.com) (I like it better than Android)"   -> Should return "http://www.apple.com"
"[Example](http://example.com)"    -> Should return "http://example.com"
"This is a message"    -> Nothing to return on this one, no link
"I like cookies (chocolate chip)"  -> Nothing to return on this one, no link
"[Frank] says 'Hello'" -> Nothing to return on this one, no link
```

I am using SQL Server 2012 (if there are differences between versions in this regard).

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to do something like that in MSSQL. You might want to use substring methods along with PATINDEX to achieve the same results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the actual data is no more complex than the stated examples, this should work without resorting to RegEx:

```
DECLARE @posts TABLE
(
   post_id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
   post_text NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
   body NVARCHAR(2048) NULL
);
INSERT INTO @posts (post_text, body) VALUES (N'first',
                                           N'Visit [Google](http://google.com)');
INSERT INTO @posts (post_text, body) VALUES (N'second',
                                           N'Get an [iPhone](http://www.apple.com)');
INSERT INTO @posts (post_text, body) VALUES (N'third',
                                           N'[Example](http://example.com)');
INSERT INTO @posts (post_text, body) VALUES (N'fourth',
                                           N'This is a message');
INSERT INTO @posts (post_text, body) VALUES (N'fifth',
                                           N'I like cookies (chocolate chip)');
INSERT INTO @posts (post_text, body) VALUES (N'sixth',
                                           N'[Frankie] says ''Relax''');
INSERT INTO @posts (post_text, body) VALUES (N'seventh',
                                           NULL);


SELECT p.post_text,
       SUBSTRING(
                  p.body,
                  CHARINDEX(N'](', p.body) + 2,
                  CHARINDEX(N')', p.body) - (CHARINDEX(N'](', p.body) + 2)
                ) AS [URL]
FROM   @posts p
WHERE  p.body like '%\[%](http%)%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Output:

```
post_text  URL
first      http://google.com
second     http://www.apple.com
third      http://example.com
```

PS:
If you *really* want to use Regular Expressions, they can only be done via SQLCLR. You can write your own or download pre-done libraries. I wrote one such library, [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/), that has a Free version that includes the RegEx functions. But those should only be used if a T-SQL solution cannot be found, which so far is not the case here.

Comment: This looks promising, but I receive the following error: `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.` From Googling, it looks like this can be due to records that don't have links (the pattern we're looking for).

Comment: @Andy : ok, that is easy to correct for. However, it would be quite helpful if you could update the question to include data that is representative of each particular case. For example, is a missing link a record with nothing between the `()`, or are the `()` missing entirely? So: `Visit [Google]()` or `Visit [Google]` or both? And others?

Comment: I've added a few additionally sample cases. It covers no link at all, a parenthetical, but no square brackets, and square brackets by no parenthetical.

Comment: @Andy : thanks. That helps. However, I just added those 3 new entries and the code still works. Your original WHERE clause filters out all 3 of the new entries ;-). Are you saying that you don't always have that WHERE condition, or is there a missing test case? I even added an entry with `NULL` for the `body` field and it still works (well, I first removed the `NOT` from the `NOT NULL` in the field definition in my `DECLARE`.

Comment: @Andy : I see that you accepted this (thanks), but just FYI, if needed, it can still be easily updated to account for situations where the WHERE clause is missing or for some reason doesn't catch a bad entry.

Comment: I appreciate that. There must be a problem in my data somewhere because your answer is correct. It functions exactly like I want. I do still get the error, but I haven't narrowed down why yet. Thanks for the help and once I figure out what data is causing an issue, I hope to apply this.

Comment: @Andy : Why don't you temporarily remove the `SUBSTRING` and replace your `WHERE` condition with `CHARINDEX(N')', p.body) - (CHARINDEX(N'](', p.body) + 2) <= 0` as that should be the only condition to get an "invalid length" error.