# Extract data from the last two square brackets SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

So I am receiving some dirty data as resultset coming from a Cube, 
Example :

- [Dates].[Fiscal Quarter].&[2014Q3]
- [Geography Incl Profit Center].[Sub-Region1].&[United States]
- [Geography Incl Profit Center].[Region].&[NA]

I am looking for a way to extract only what's inside the last two brackets,
base on the last example I would need as end result the following:

- '2014Q3'
- 'United States'
- 'NA'

these results are coming from 3 different columns, my idea is the find a way to position the index on the last '[' left square bracket, and delete anything that is on the left from it, then delete the last Character from the string which it should be ']'

This is SQL, so any help on how to accomplish this will be excellent,

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128782/sql-server-2012-extract-regex-groups for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another option

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('[Dates].[Fiscal Quarter].&[2014Q3]'),
('[Geography Incl Profit Center].[Sub-Region1].&[United States]'),
('[Geography Incl Profit Center].[Region].&[NA]'),
('[Geography Incl Profit Center].[Region]')        -- No Value

Select SomeVal = replace(substring(SomeCol,charindex('&[',SomeCol+'&[')+2,500),']','')
 From  @YourTable A
```

Returns

```
SomeVal
2014Q3
United States
NA
```

Comment: Only bad thing is if the field value gets long it will fail. Interesting approach though.

Comment: @scsimon Agreed, but only if the last node is +500 characters.  I would assume that would be a non-event    :)

Comment: This one did the trick, by far was the simplest as well, thanks for all the help everyone : replace(substring(SomeCol,charindex('&[',SomeCol+'&[')+2,500),']','')

Comment: @JuanCarlosArayaPortuguez Happy it helped

Answer (score 2):

Here's **one** example of how. It works for all your test cases. Just replace the `@var` with your column name, of course.

```
declare @table table (bracketColumn varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('[Geography Incl Profit Center].[Sub-Region1].&[United States]'),
('[Dates].[Fiscal Quarter].&[2014Q3]'),
('[Geography Incl Profit Center].[Region].&[NA]')

select 
    replace(
            replace(
                    right(bracketColumn,charindex('[',reverse(bracketColumn)))
                    ,'[','')
            ,']','')
from
    @table
```

**How it works**

1. It reverses your field value to find the first instance of `]` in the reverse text. This is the same thing as the last '[' when looking at it normal. Doing this, we can id the index of this value regardless of how many brackets come before it.
2. Once we have identified that, we use `RIGHT` to return everything from this location to the end of the string. That essentially leaves us with `[yourLastBracket]`.
3. Then, we replace `[` and `]` with empty strings, resulting in your final result

Comment: You could also do this: select REPLACE(RIGHT(@var, CHARINDEX('[', REVERSE(@var))-1), ']', '')

Comment: Another good idea @TheEsisia. I'd add that as an answer so the OP has options.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove that extra `REPLACE` usage from @scsimon solution using:

```
declare @table table (bracketColumn varchar(64))
     insert into @table
     values
     ('[Geography Incl Profit Center].[Sub-Region1].&[United States]'),
     ('[Dates].[Fiscal Quarter].&[2014Q3]'),
     ('[Geography Incl Profit Center].[Region].&[NA]')


SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(bracketColumn, CHARINDEX('[', REVERSE(bracketColumn))-1), ']', '') 
FROM @table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Reverse(string2) from(Select Left(string1,charindex('[',string1)-1) as string2 from ( Select Left(Reverse(column),len(column)-1) as string1 )L)F
```

String 1 will be the input string without last square braces and also in reversed form.

String 2 will be the substring of the reversed string till the position of first appearance of square braces -1.(Actual requirement but still in reversed status)

String 3 will be the actual Sub-String required...