# SQL Query to bifurcate text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have field in my table with below text and I need to bifurcate them into 4 columns with values out of the text.

The values should be like

1. in 1st column `1234` --Next to word Warning Code
2. in 2nd column `i am from a city` --Next to word Message
3. in 3rd column `WARNING`     --Next to word Severity

Basically I need to bifurcate the values after the specific words in text.
I have been trying using substring,LEN etc but none are not working because these words are not at same character distance in all all row
Please help.

i work in ms sql server

Comment: `charindex()` and maybe `patindex()` will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26128947/5657035) can be adapted to work for you. Essentially, we can search for certain substrings (`Warning Code: >`, `< Message: \n\n >`, etc) and use the indexes to determine the substrings you need.

For instance,

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(
        p.body,
        CHARINDEX('Warning Code: >', p.body) + 16,
        CHARINDEX('< Message:', p.body) - (CHARINDEX('Warning Code: >', p.body) + 16)
    ) AS warning_code
FROM
    TABLENAME p
```

which is fugly as all hell but might work as a starting point. And doesn't require enabling CLR integration, which you would need to run regular expressions. (If that's acceptable, use a regex - they are much more concise and arguably a little less brittle)

Answer (score 0):

If your string is

> The Product Order #####, and Fulfilment Order #####, ===============WARNING=================== Warning Code: >1234< Message: Insufficient lead time for order.WARNING< ==============END WARNING===================

With the help of [Regex](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/) you can try this in SQL:

```
declare @query varchar(1000) = 'The Product Order #####, and Fulfilment Order #####, ===============WARNING=================== Warning Code: >1234< Message: Insufficient lead time for order.<Severity: >WARNING< ==============END WARNING==================='
select dbo.RegExMatch('(?<=\>)\d+',@query,1),
       dbo.RegExMatch('(?<=Message:).*?(?=\<)',@query,1),
       dbo.RegExMatch('(?<=Severity: \>).*?(?=\<)',@query,1)
```