# Get pattern matched substring from string in sql server

Tags: sql-server, regex

Get pattern matched sub string from string in SQL server
for example my string is `'Test{Ab}{CV}Ad testing'`
I need out put of above string `'Ab'` and `'CV'` which is available in `'{}'`
I need out put without brackets and selected sub string in rows

```
DECLARE @Template NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Test{Ab}{CV}Ad testing'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2012 : extract Regex groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128782/sql-server-2012-extract-regex-groups)

Comment: Are you looking for a solution with RegEx only? You can get the results needed without using RegEx.

Comment: i need only results ,with or without regex

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60

Comment: @RakeshV No, share the results of `select @@version;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work even when you have more than two {} placeholders:

```
DECLARE @Template NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Test{Ab}{CV}Ad testing'

DECLARE @counter INT = 1 
DECLARE @inside INT = 0
DECLARE @curr VARCHAR(1) = ''
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

WHILE(@counter < LEN(@Template))
BEGIN 
    SET @curr = SUBSTRING(@Template, @counter, @counter)
    SET @inside = CASE 
                    WHEN @curr = '{' THEN 1
                    WHEN @curr = '}' THEN 0
                    ELSE @inside
                  END

    SET @output = CASE 
                    WHEN @inside = 1 THEN @output + @curr 
                    WHEN @curr = '}' THEN @output + @curr + '_'
                    ELSE @output 
                  END 

    SET @counter = @counter + 1 

    --SELECT @curr, @inside, @output
END

SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT( @output ,'_')
```